# In Action Script: How can I search a substring in a string and then truncate the characters that follow my substring

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

In Action Script: How can I search a substring in a string and then truncate the characters that follow my substring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String.indexOf(substring)` will return you the first part, `String.slice()` with parameters will let you truncate your string. [The manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html)